# Excel Formula Help: Finding difference between max and min timestamps within specific column ID

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula

In column A I have location ID's

For example:

| Location ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021/12/06 06:04:34:00 |
| 1234 | 2021/12/06 06:08:25:00 |
| 1234 | 2021/12/06 07:05:41:00 |
| 1234 | 2021/12/06 07:07:16:00 |
| 4567 | 2021/12/06 07:25:57:00 |
| 4567 | 2021/12/06 07:48:02:00 |
| 6789 | 2021/12/06 08:17:27:00 |

Is there a way that I can automate Excel to find the differences of the max and min timestamp for Location ID 1234, and similarly with 4567 & 6789 respectively?

Google Sheets or Excel are my limitations

Comment: Look into `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS`.

Comment: You could also do this with Pivot Tables and/or Power Query

Comment: Is this an Excel question or a Google Sheets question. They are not the same. Please remove whichever tag(s) do not apply to your situation.

Comment: Use unique() to get a list of locations to work with.

Comment: At the very least, let us know here what the sheet name of the original data is and what the real ranges are for "Location ID" and "Timestamp." And are your timestamps *strings* that really run all the way through milliseconds as shown in your post? Better still, share a link to a sample spreadsheet with the posted data in it. Set up the original data just as it will be in your real sheet, including sheet name and data locations. In addition, do you have to use the resulting difference for more comparisons and/or math afterward, or do you just need to view them?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the values in column `B` are numeric datetime values, you can get the difference between the min and max value per each location with `query()` in Google Sheets like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { A1:A, to_pure_number(B1:B) }, 
    "select Col1, max(Col2) - min(Col2) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label max(Col2) - min(Col2) 'Difference' ", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

Format the second column in the result table as **Format > Number > Duration**.

If the values in column `B` are not numeric datetime values but text strings that look like datetimes (`isnumber()` gets false), you can convert them like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / value( substitute( substitute(B2:B, "/", "-"), ":00", "" ) ) ^ -1 ) )`

Format the result as **Format > Number > Date time**.